# postgres convert_from(X, 'UTF8') equivalent in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, utf-8

I have a SQL statement where a make a conversion with "convert_from(X, 'UTF8')" on a 'bytea'-field in PostgreSQL. I want to make the conversion not in SQL but in PHP. Is there an equivalent function for doing this in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

```
iconv('UTF-8', $targetCharset, $x)
```

or

```
mb_convert_encoding($x, $targetCharset, 'UTF-8')
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php
http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding

You will have to specify the target character set, which is implied by the database encoding in the Postgres function.

Comment: Well, what is your end goal? What do you want to convert to?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that postgresql returns the field hex-coded. My solution in PHP now looks like this:

```
$str = pack('H*', str_replace('\x', '', $obj->BinData));
```

With this it is possible to retrieve text of a bytea-field.